# PYSpark/scala not able to install on ubuntu 12.04 due to unable to install java7

Tags: java, ubuntu

i will not able to install Scala / python  because of java7 or 6 not able install on ubuntu12.04.
even i will try to install java7 manually by download tar file and put in usr/lib/jvm folder. everything goes fine but if i give java -version on command prompt.it show binary is not executable.

kindly provide some help is there any way to install java7 so that i may install Scala / spark on ubuntu

Comment: I believe support for Ubuntu 12.04 ended in april. You might want to consider updating to a newer version of Ubuntu instead.

Comment: thanks for your reply.

Comment: i have tried on version 14 and 16 also. for past one week i uninstall and do the process. in every version of ubuntu. java jdk is moved ,404 error,unable to install, but i install java8 it worked fine.but for scala and other software will search for java 7 version, so unable to install

Comment: As far as I understand Spark works fine in Java 8.